# Created channels don't appear in the list of active Google Analytics channels

Tags: google-analytics

In the default channel grouping, I've created some channels which are labeled like `system` and `user defined`. The green alert, which pops up after channel saving, informed me about the time gap of up to 24 hours before channels will be active.

Since then, more than 72 hours have passed by.  Only one of those appears in the list of active channels at `Acquisition` → `All Traffic` → `Channels`. They are still displayed in the channel administration, but not as active channels.

What happens to the rest of created channels? Should I just wait? Is there something that could have been done wrong during channel creation which would lead to failed channel activation?

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of the table showing the Channels report?